# Recursively iterate object and conditionally run a function

Tags: javascript

I need a function to recursively iterate an object and if the given condition is met to pass the key value to a callback function in order to get the replacement to replace the matching key. Here is a more suggestive example:

```
const replacement1 = { a: 1 };
const replacement2 = { b: 1 };

const getReplacement = (id) => {
    if (id == 1) return replacement1;
    if (id == 2) return replacement2;
};

const obj = {
    foo: 2,
    replaceMe: 1,
    bar: {
        replaceMe: 2,
    },
};

function update(obj, key) {
    // iterate object keys recursivelly
    // if key = replaceMe then replace that key using getReplacement(obj[key])
}

console.log(update(obj, 'replaceMe'));

// should output => {foo: 2, a: 1, bar: { b: 1 } };
```

Sorry if the purpose for this doesn't make sense, it's just an example I could write in a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below. Explanation is in comments.

```js
const replacement1 = { a: 1 };
const replacement2 = { b: 1 };

const getReplacement = (id) => {
    if (id == 1) return replacement1;
    if (id == 2) return replacement2;
};

const obj = {
    foo: 2,
    replaceMe: 1,
    bar: {
        replaceMe: 2,
    },
};

function update(obj, key) {
  // iterate over all key of object
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {    
    if (k == key) { // process matching key object
      // get replacement object
      Object.assign(obj, getReplacement(obj[key]));
      // delete key property
      delete obj[key];
    } else if (typeof obj[k] === "object") { // Check if nested object is having key property, if yes then process that      
      update(obj[k], key);
    }
  });

  return obj;
}

console.log(update(obj, 'replaceMe')); 
// should output => {foo: 2, a: 1, bar: { b: 1 } };
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I can't decide which one is better, yours or the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

If you like to mutate the object, you could take an object for the replacements and iterate the nested objects as well.

```js
const
    update = (object, key, replacements) => {
        if (key in object) {
            Object.assign(object, replacements[object[key]]);
            delete object[key];
        }
        Object.values(object).forEach(v => {
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') update(v, key, replacements);
        });
        return object;
    },
    obj = { foo: 2, replaceMe: 1, bar: { replaceMe: 2 } };


console.log(update(obj, 'replaceMe', { 1: { a: 1 }, 2: { b: 1 } })); // { foo: 2, a: 1, bar: { b: 1 } };
```

Comment: Your solution is nice, thank you. I can use it for another case, but this time @Karan solution suits better since I can use the getReplacement function like a callback.